# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

so I'm trying to make this bot with selenium but when I'm trying to use the send keys func it doesn't work
I'm stuck on it for hours and I cant seem to find to solve the problem please if anyone has any idea I beg you to help me thanks.

```
print(driver.title)
tos = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="pop"]/button')
tos.click()
time.sleep(5)
name = driver.find_element("ID", "inpNick")
time.sleep(5)
name.send_keys('baby')
time.sleep(50)


driver.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\SexiKiller41\Downloads\a\catchno1se.py", line 17, in <module>
    name = driver.find_element("ID", "inpNick")
  File "C:\Users\SexiKiller41\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\SexiKiller41\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\SexiKiller41\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.122)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0039ACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x0032EE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x0022B7BD+571325]
    Ordinal0 [0x0025A745+763717]
    Ordinal0 [0x0025AE1B+765467]
    Ordinal0 [0x0028D0F2+970994]
    Ordinal0 [0x00277364+881508]
    Ordinal0 [0x0028B56A+963946]
    Ordinal0 [0x00277136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x0024FEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x00250F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0064EED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00640D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0042A03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00428DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x0033682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x0033B128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x0033B215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00346484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7753FEF9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D37BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77D37B8E+238]


[Done] exited with code=1 in 9.895 seconds
```

I was trying to enter text to an input on a website

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# id instead of ID
name = driver.find_element("id", "inpNick")  

# or
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
name = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inpNick")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead `driver.find_element("ID", "inpNick")` try

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "inpNick")
```

Also, no need to add delays between locating element and clicking it or sending keys to it.
Delays are meaningful **before** locating the element to make the element rendered on the page.
It is much better to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits than hardcoded sleeps.
Improved, your code can be as following:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

print(driver.title)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pop"]/button'))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "inpNick"))).send_keys('baby')
```